# 404 after autodeploying servlet to glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I tried to deploy a servlet I have created to Glassfish application server, and I seem to have hit a bit of a stumbling block. The code deploys fine to the auto deploy folder, and once it's deployed the following is written to the log file:

```
[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.303+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|[AutoDeploy] Selecting file /opt/glassfish-2.1.b60e/domains/imageTransformer/autodeploy/image-transformer.war for autodeployment.|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.304+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|Autoundeploying application :image-transformer|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.360+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|
classLoader = WebappClassLoader
  delegate: true
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
EJBClassLoader : 
urlSet = []
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> java.net.URLClassLoader@39cf701c

|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.361+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.out|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@5e7408d9|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.487+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|[AutoDeploy] Successfully autoundeployed : /opt/glassfish-2.1.b60e/domains/imageTransformer/autodeploy/image-transformer.war.|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.612+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|deployed with moduleid = image-transformer|#]

[#|2009-03-16T13:41:29.783+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Timer-7;|[AutoDeploy] Successfully autodeployed : /opt/glassfish-2.1.b60e/domains/imageTransformer/autodeploy/image-transformer.war.|#]
```

So no obvious errors, but after that I get a 404 from accessing the path that the servlet should be bound to. Is there another step that I need to go through?

the web.xml in my WAR file looks like this:

```
<web-app>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>my.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: Is this a first time deploy or are you re-deploying the application ?

Comment: This is the first time I am deploying this application. I've never deployed it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with this deployment. Firstly, there is a requirement for a second configuration file to be included in the `WEB-INF` directory, named `sun-web.xml`. Its contents need to be something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 8.1 Servlet 2.4//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_4-1.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/MyServlet </context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

It seems to have the potential to get a lot more complex than this (see [the documentation](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-2634/6n4tl5kp3?a=view#gchwx)).

Secondly, I had to change the header for the `web.xml` file, so it read accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Note the headers indicating that this is servlet spec 2.4.

Finally, it also seems that you can't access this servlet directly; you have to prepend `MyServlet/` (or the servlet specific name) to the beginning of the path. So to access this servlet requires you to visit `/MyServlet/hello`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified web.xml; I simply added the full path of the config directory for ords.

```
<display-name>Oracle Application Express Listener</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>config.dir</param-name>
    <!-- Enter the location where configuration settings should be stored -->
    <param-value>/odata/apps/ords/config</param-value>
</context-param>
```

it works no matter if sun-web.xml is there or not.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly does that answer the question for which the OP already found a solution 6 years ago...?